# Normed Linear Spaces, if $x$ and $y$ satisfies $||x+y||=||x||+||y||$, then $||ax+by||=a||x||+b||y||$, for $a,b\in \mathbb{R}_+$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

I wanted to prove that, in a normed linear space $X$, if $x,y\in X$ satisfies $||x+y||=||x||+||y||$, then $||ax+by||=a||x||+b||y||$ for all $a,b\in \mathbb{R}_+$.

I could prove it using inner product and continuity argument but my professor said that I am not allowed to use inner products while proving this.
Any help or hint will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The professor said to do not use the inner product because not all norms have an associated inner product.

Comment: Recall that A Banach space is a complete metric space with a norm, while a Hilbert space is a Banach space whose norm is associated to an inner product. An inner product induces a norm by $||x|| = \sqrt{<x,x>}$.  However, the converse doesn't need to hold as the norm isn't always expressable in terms of the inner product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$
(a+b)(\|x\|+\|y\|)=(a+b)\|x+y\|=\|(ax+by)+(bx+ay)\|\le \|ax+by\|+\|bx+ay\|
$$
$$
\le \|ax\|+\|by\|+\|bx\|+\|ay\|= (a+b)(\|x\|+\|y\|).
$$
Thus
$$
(1) \quad \|ax+by\|+\|bx+ay\|= (a+b)(\|x\|+\|y\|).
$$
Moreover
$$
(2) \quad \|ax+by\| \le a\|x\|+ b\|y\|, ~~ \|bx+ay\| \le b\|x\|+a\|y\|.
$$
If $<$ holds in one of the inequalities in (2) this would contradict (1).

Comment: Very sleek indeed!